# How do I hide a parent element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose the following HTML:

```
<li class="fooli">
   <a class="foo" href="javascript:foo(this);">anchor</a>
</li>
<li class="fooli">
   <a class="foo" href="javascript:foo(this);">anchor</a>
</li>
```

and the following Javascript (using jquery 1.3.2):

```
function foo(anchor) {
  alert($(anchor).attr('href'));
}
```

My goal is to be able to hide the li that is clicked on, but I can't assign them unique ids. Thus, I want to do it positionally (i.e. identify the particular anchor clicked on) by something like $(anchor).parent().hide().

However, the alert above returns "undefined", so it's not obvious to me that I even have the right jquery object.

How do I figure out what object $(anchor) is?  In particular, how do I see what attributes it has, what class it has, what HTML element it is, etc?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Can't you do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.foo").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

with:

```
<li class="fooli"><a class="foo" href="#">anchor</a></li>
<li class="fooli"><a class="foo" href="#">anchor</a></li>
```

Answer (score 6):

`$(...)` in jQuery is never a single HTML element; it's always a list of them.

You can use `.get()` to convert to a regular Javascript list or, better, use `.each()`:

```
$(anchor).each(function() { alert(this) });
```

This will give you something like `[object HTMLAElement]`.  You'd have to use `for/in` to examine it entirely, but `.tagName` and `.innerHTML` are probably good enough to figure out where you are.

I also like to use `$(...).css('outline', '1px solid lime')` to find elements.  It makes them hard to miss and easy to pinpoint with Firebug.

Addendum: I definitely agree with the above answer about separating your Javascript from your HTML.  Don't inline JS.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question I asked.